# how can I integrate two plots on Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have these datas for each algorithm.

I need the graph of each algorithm according to it's datas.

And in addition, in each of 3 graphs, they should also be combined with graphs of
x^2 , log x^x in base 2, 
x in order.

table file: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/33787465/hw1%20tablo.xlsx

How can it be done?

[image: alg]

Answer (score 1):

If you have the data in Matlab, do something like

```
plot(alg1size, [alg1time, alg1time .^ 2, log2(alg1time .^ 2)]);
```

If not use `xlsread` as suggested in the comments

Comment: no I dont have data in Matlab, I just need the graphs with datas from a table

Comment: @Okan You can copy the data to matlab or use [`xlsread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) to read `.xls` file in to matlab and then use Mark's solution.

Comment: @Mark you can use `log2` function instead of dividing by `log(2)`.